# How to gain access to each menu item in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have some menu items in a menu at location "main-menu".
By using `wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) );` , i get all the items in a div.

Now i just need to show 10 menu items in present div and the remanining in other div (say id="new") just adjacent to it. Again if the div with id "new" has 10 menu-items in it, again a new div will be created and the remaining items are shown in it.

So is there a way to access the array that contains these menu-items?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A menu is a list of items, [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) just displays the menu. If you want to learn how to create a menu or get its items on an array you can modify and display, check:

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items

Answer (score 0):

you can read and know

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu
  http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide
  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items

you can Achive this by Jquery on page load.